# Is there a bug in MagickUnsharpMaskImage method for MagickWand C?

Tags: c, imagemagick, magickwand

I have a below CLI and trying to achieve same result using magickwand c.
Everything seems to be perfect or don't know may be I missed something but the MagickUnsharpMaskImage is not working for me. Check my source code. I also attached source and two output images generated by CLI and C API.

CLI

```
convert testsharp.jpg -unsharp 0x1 unsharpC.jpg
```

C code

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    MagickWand * wand;
    wand = NewMagickWand();
    MagickReadImage(wand, "testsharp.jpg");
    MagickUnsharpMaskImage(wand, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    MagickWriteImage(wand, "unsharpW.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```

source image

[image]

output image using CLI

[image]

output image using C

[image]

**ImageMagick version**

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-5 Q16 x86_64 2017-05-23 http://www.imagemagick.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the man](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php)

> `MagickUnsharpMaskImage()` sharpens an image. We convolve the image with a Gaussian operator of the given radius and standard deviation (sigma). **For reasonable results, radius should be larger than sigma**. Use a radius of 0 and `UnsharpMaskImage()` selects a suitable radius for you.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

You call it passing `radius=0` `sigma=1.0`

Moreover [default value for those parameters are](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#unsharp)

1. **radius** The radius of the Gaussian, in pixels, not counting the center pixel **(default 0).**
2. **sigma** The standard deviation of the Gaussian, in pixels **(default 1.0)**.
3. **gain** The fraction of the difference between the original and the blur image that is added back into the original **(default 1.0)**.
4. **threshold** The threshold, as a fraction of QuantumRange, needed to apply the difference amount **(default 0.05)**.

Correct [c](/questions/tagged/c) code to

```
MagickUnsharpMaskImage(wand, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.05);
```

Comment: Yep. The implementor of the C library will need to respect the [defaults](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickWand/mogrify.c#L3222) if attempting to match CLI behavior.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't notice that. Thank you!